# Navigate between two PHP files or pages without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 PHP file one is `index.php` and other is `gallery.php`.

I would like users to be able to move between `index.php` and `gallery.php` (and vice versa) without reloading or redirecting the current PHP page.

Link to my website: clickatcareerherokupapp.com

Comment: Use ajax(javascript) to load content dynamically

Comment: post the code you have tried so far

Comment: I tried with jquery (history.pushstate) but still failed

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16l-fPCnrB9TwDsAFOw5ZU0l1zZBX5_Gj

Comment: @Ankrish do you want to make gallery visible on the index page on click of a button or a tag ? or do you want to completely replace the contents of the index.php file ?

Comment: Cleaned the title, clarified the content.

Comment: clarified UX direction

Comment: @Alexander I want to replace the contents of index without using jquery load() function

Comment: @Ankrish , well then u've choosen the wrong library , look into react !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I dont know about react. can you guide me please

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's .load() function, which I believe is part of the Ajax api. You can load php files into lets say a div, table, or whatever dom type you're working with.(assuming your only loading html content generated by php) In my opinion, this is easier than using the native ajax functions because you don't have to worry about return types,send types, etc.